# Saying "Remember you're still alive"

Tags: translation, phrase-requests

I'd like to know how you say *Remember that you're still alive*...

I found this あなたはまだ生きていることを忘れないでください with the meaning of *Don't forget that you're still alive*. It's not strictly necessary the literal translation, but I need the sense not to change.

I need it for a tattoo and I'd like it to be a single phrase but divided in 2 columns, possibly the first longer than the second... I don't know if I explained my self, I mean that I don't want a simple *Remember* / *You're still alive*, but *Remember that you're still alive*.

I undestand my request is a little too precise (and maybe impossibile), but, you know, trying doesn't have any costs.

Thank you very much in advise

Comment: This just sounds like a translation request hidden behind the thin veil of "here's something else I found"...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember that you're still alive...

> - あなたはまだ生きていることを忘れないでください

- 生｛い｝きているなら 死｛し｝ぬな *Do not die, if you're still alive*.
- 生｛い｝きているなら 生｛い｝きろ *Go on living, if you're still alive*.
- 生｛い｝きたと言｛い｝えるまで 死｛し｝ぬな *Do not die until you have accomplished your life*.
- 死｛し｝ぬまで 勝手｛かって｝に死｛し｝ぬな *Don't die without permission until death permits.*
- 死｛し｝ぬな、生｛い｝きろ。 *Do not die, but live.*
- 人生｛じんせい｝死｛し｝ぬまで 気｛き｝を抜｛ぬ｝くな *Don't loose your concentration until you die*.

## EDIT

> what if I'd want to underline the adverb of time "still"?

I'll make the situation and conditions clear before answering about "still".

> (1) Remember that you're still alive...
> I found this あなたはまだ生きていることを忘れないでください with the meaning of Don't forget that you're still alive.
> (2) Don't forget that you're still alive.
> (3) あなたはまだ生きていることを忘れないでください

It is clear that "you" in (1) presented by the questioner is in a life or death situation.

The heart of "you" is beating. "You" are breathing faintly. Maybe there is no consciousness.

It's possible that "you" may die without recovering consciousness. "You" is more serious when the word with "still" is needed.

The person who says (1) to "you" probably knows "you" and doesn't want "you" to die, and when he/she are calling out with (1), he/she wants "you" to recover consciousness.

The nuances of English in (1) and (2) may be different, but for me who is a Japanese, there is no big difference between them with having the same meaning as (3).
Please speak (1) or (2) quickly. I will speak (3) in the same way as you.
Perhaps (3) took time more than twice (1) or (2).
We wouldn't use a long phrase like (3) in such an emergency. In a situation where it is necessary to say "still", you have to speak to "you" in a short time.
In such a case, you know the person to whom you are saying the phrase and you can understand the condition of "you", so you need not to say "you" or "still" in (1). In addition, there is a reason that it takes more time to say the phrase without omitting them.
I showed some Japanese translations in my original answer, but in fact the Japanese will actually say such expressions briefly as follows in the situation.

- 目｛め｝を覚｛さ｝まして！
- 目｛め｝を覚｛さ｝ませ！
- （私｛わたし｝/俺｛おれ｝が）分｛わ｝かるか?
- （おい、）何｛なん｝とか言｛い｝え!
- 死｛し｝んだらだめ（よ/だ）！
- 死｛し｝ぬな（よ）！

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much Mackygoo!

You've perfectly caught what I meant. 

Can I ask you another curiosity, just for my own interest?
What if I want to say "remember it!" with imperative purpose?
I searched for it but I didn't find anything with that exact meaning. 

I hope my question doesn't break any of the rules of this forum. If it does, I sincerly apologize, it's the first time I ask something and I don't know the policy.

Thank you again for everything.

Comment: I don't know about any specific policy (there might be one), but unrelated follow-up questions should be put into separate new posts.  Not only does it place an unfair expectation on the individual who took the time and effort to reply to your original question, but the answer can be more involved and complicated than you expect.

Comment: Having said that, 覚えてくれ・覚えといてくれ (strong suggestion),　覚えなさい (used with children, etc.),　覚えろ (order - used with subordinates or if angry), 覚えてね (softer suggestion). It really depends on who is speaking, who is being spoken to, and what nuance (strength of message) is desired.

Comment: Thank you very much, user27280. My 2nd question was obviously related to the 1rst one, I presented it as a different curiosity only because Makygoo had already properly solved my problem... but I'm just defending my innocent purposes, I got the point and the next time I'll surely write a new post ;) Speaking of serious stuff, my _Remember it!_ should have a medium strenght, it's like: _Hey, you're alive. Remember it!_ It's imperative but not surely angry or else... I think that maybe your 2nd or 4th translation could fit with my request.
(Thank you again for everything)

Comment: ^  "Remember it!" ってどっちかっていうと「忘れるな！」って言うことが多いんじゃないですかね… "Remember Pearl Harbor" も「真珠湾攻撃を**忘れるな** 」ですし。。（または文脈によって「思い出せ！」とか。）「覚えてくれ、覚えなさい、覚えろ、覚えてね」ってどっちかっていうと "memorize" っぽい意味での "remember" って感じじゃないですかね・・　（「覚えて(い)ろ(よ)！」「覚えとけ！」はまた別の意味がありますけどね。。）

Comment: `Hey, you're alive. Remember it!` <-- 「あなたは生きてるのよ/お前は生きてるんだ！覚えなさい/覚えて/覚えていろ/覚えろ！etc.」なんて訳したら絶対におかしい。。。

Comment: @Rea >What if I want to say "remember it!" with imperative purpose? Chocolate posted a good answer in the comment as 「忘れるな！」. I would like to say in another way like 「忘れるのではないぞ！」,「忘れるんでないぞ！」or 「忘れんじゃないぞ！」 The three expressions have the same meaning, and the last one is offten used in a conversation.

Comment: Thank you so much guys, you've all been so kind ^^ In the middle of all the variants of "remember" I've notice that you reported me the expression "you're alive" (as I requested)... but what if I'd want to underline the adverb of time "still"? Not with the meaning of "despite all the bad things" but in the pure meaning of "you're keeping doing it". I don't know if I explained my self. I would really like to know Japanese as you do to understand on my own the little subtleties that make an expression different from another.

Comment: @Rea: >what if I'd want to underline the adverb of time "still"?  I answered the question in my EDIT.

Comment: Thank you again @Mackygoo, for your time, kindness and dedication: you explained yourself very well. I think I've understood the difference of the two way to think behind the two different languages... (And I apologize if even my English is terrible, I'm obviously not Anglo-Saxon :'(... ). I will never stop thanking you for everything you told me.